# What is the significance of the character "j" at the end of a Roman Numeral?

Tags: england, 17th-century, date

While using an old (1907) book of transcriptions (on-line) [The Parish Register of Gargrave in the County of York](http://www.archive.org/stream/publicationsyor04socigoog#page/n5/mode/2up) , I was puzzled by the number of dates recorded in the 16th and early 17th centuries that could be read easily as Roman numerals except for the addition of a *j* at the end.
[image]

The pattern (if there is one) seems to be that if the number would ordinarily end with *i* then *j* is appended, but if it ends with *v* or *x* then there may be no extra character before the ordinal superscript (but in one case, there is!).

I thought this may be a style quirk of a particular clerk, but now I am seeing it in other sources (but all Yorkshire based and pre-1700, because that is what I am reading at the moment).

1. Is this a real phenomenon or just a coincidence?
2. How widespread was the practice?
3. What on earth did it mean? Why did they do it?

Comment: So is ij = 2, iij = 3, etc? Or is ij = 1, iij =2?

Comment: @Jane  The "j" is treated as an "i", so iij=3 etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The letter *j* originated as a "swash" (florish) character at the end of Roman numerals, and only later became useful as a separate character.

A *j* was used for the final *i*, to make it clear the number had ended.

Until quite recent times it was still the recommended practice to use a final *j* in medical prescriptions, to avoid misunderstandings.  See these [instructions from 1919](http://books.google.com/books?id=XesRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA582#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

So you should interpret *xvij* as 17, not 16.  It's part of the number, not something appended.